RabbitMQ vs Nats JS
I am new to RabbitMQ and wanted to know the difference between RabbitMQ and Nats JetStream. Most importantly, they both have something like two-level routing. I would like to understand in which cases these technologies should be used.
I tried to use Nats JS in my project and this look are very good. And now I think its a seems technologies.
